# Using doReturn chain is not working properly

Tags: junit

I am using doReturn (firstInstance). doReturn (secondInstance).when(mock).someMethod()....... This is not working properly

While running the test it is not return the instances in proper manner.

For first call it sometimes returns second instance and for second call it returns first instance.
So sometimes test are failing sometimes it passes.

Comment: This is a wrong syntax for multiple returns, it takes varargs `doReturn(Object toBeReturned, Object... toBeReturnedNext)`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating which mocking framework you are using. I also suggest formatting your code (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)